# How to share user authentication state between Flutter app and web app using Firebase?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, sharedpreferences

Using Firebase authentication, how can I ensure that a user accessing my Flutter mobile app and web app is the same user, and how can I share data between the two platforms? Specifically, I want to retrieve a user ID generated by Firebase on the mobile app, and pass it to a web app using a WebView. How can I accomplish this?

I tried using shared preferences plugin:

```
// To write data to shared_preferences:

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<void> saveId(String id) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('id', id);
}


// To read data from shared_preferences:

Future<String?> getId() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('id');
}
```

The goal of this code is to enable users to maintain a consistent identity when switching between a mobile app and a web app. However, the current implementation is encountering an issue where the user ID passed from the mobile app to the web app is not being retrieved properly on the web side. Any help in identifying the cause of the issue and resolving it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to describe in more detail the strategy you're using now, and what's not working the way you expect with the code you've showing. Presumably you also have some code on the webview side that's cooperating with the dart code in the app. We'll likely need to see that as well.